# How to cache a custom list using Redis?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, redis, servicestack

I have two classes for each entity; one to represent a single item and another for a collection of those entities;

For a single entity `(BaseItem<-MenuItem)`, i have a base class `BaseItem` which `MenuItem` inherits from.

For a collection of MenuItems i have the following hierarchy; `(List<T> <- BaseItemList<MenuItem> <- MenuItemList)`.

Now, whenever i use the code below to cache a collection of MenuItem (MenuItemList), it works 
with no errors;

```
using (var client = _manager.GetClient()) {
     IRedisTypedClient<T> typeObject = client.As<T>();
     typeObject.SetEntry(key, value);
}
```

However, when i try to retrieve it from redis i get the error below;

```
using (var client = _manager.GetClient()) {
   if (client.ContainsKey(key)) {
      IRedisTypedClient<T> typeObject = client.As<T>();
      cachedObject = typeObject.GetValue(key);
   }
}
```

The error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

StackTrace

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeListWithElements`2.ParseGenericList(String value, Type createListType, ParseStringDelegate parseFn)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeList`2.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetParseFn>b__0(String value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonReader`1.Parse(String value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer`1.DeserializeFromString(String value)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.Generic.RedisTypedClient`1.DeserializeValue(Byte[] value)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.Generic.RedisTypedClient`1.GetValue(String key)
   at TryoutStuff.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Orson\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ICS\TryoutStuff\Program.cs:line 75
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives it away

typeObject.GetValue(key) returns a value, but cachedObject is expecting to be assigned to an actual object instance.